# Is there a way to not specify version in wso2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to deploy a Backend API on **Wso2-APIM 2.6.0**. This Backend API has its versioning in endpoint.

```
/v1/devices
```

Now if I add version while creating Wso2 API (coz Version field is mandatory), I will end up having two versioning mechanism in my URL.

```
curl -k -X GET "https://88.8.88.88:8243/device-management-api**/1.0/v1/**devices?limit=20&page=0&sort=id%2Cdesc" -H "accept: application/hal+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer AAA"
```

Is there a way I can not specify version in wso2? I guess I should be able to make changes to synapse-config to do the same.

1. Can someone please point me to the right location?
2. I am sure this is a very common issue everyone come across.
3. How do developers get around it? What is the norm in the industry?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 (recommended):**

When you configure the endpoint for the API, configure it with the backend version included. Eg. Set the endpoint like this.

```
https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:yyyy/device-service/v1/
```

Then you can drop the "backend" version when you invoke. Eg.

```
https://88.8.88.88:8243/device-management-api/1.0/devices
```

This is recommended because you shouldn't expose the backend version to the user. Instead what you should expose is the APIM's API version.

**Option 2:**

Tick the `Default version` in the manage tab.

[image]

Then you can drop the version when you invoke. Eg. Both of these will work.

```
https://88.8.88.88:8243/device-management-api/v1/devices
https://88.8.88.88:8243/device-management-api/1.0/v1/devices
```

Comment: Hi @Bee. What about if the versioning we have is at resource level and not at backend.
For example, I can have a backend with api/v1/devices (resource 1) and api/v2/devices (resource 2).

First approach does not work, because I cannot use "api/v1" as the endpoint for the backend, because I also have an "api/v2" url for that backend. The only option I see is having a separate API in WSO2 for each resource, which is not very convenient.

Second approach might work, but we would have two urls in the developer portal.

Comment: in your example, v1 and v2 are the only parts than differentiate the 2 resources. In that case, you will have to define the resources including them.

Comment: In the same backend I can have multiple types of resources: api/v1/devices, api/v2/devices, api/v1/users, api/v1/roles, etc. I believe I don't understand your answer clearly. If my backend endpoint is "url/api", and my resources "/v1/devices", "/v2/devices", "/v1/users", etc, then I would have the version duplicated in WSO2. The options I see are one WSO2 API per resource (instead of backend), or using the default version approach. Is there another way? Thanks

Comment: I have the following idea:

I can put in the version field the text "api", so my url will be "gateway/context/api/v1/devices"

Comment: For those interesed, another approach would be to use the full resource path as the API endpoint. This means one API per resource. For example, endpoint = "backend/api/v1/devices", and the OpenAPI definition with only one resource on the base path "/"